# GroupBy using list of records in Elm

Tags: elm

What would an Elm function definition look like which takes a list of records, and perform a groupby operation (see example below)? Using a SQL analogy, I'm basically trying to achieve `select last, sum(age) from table group by last`in Elm.

```
[{name= "John", last= "Smith", age= 10}
      ,{name="Jason", last= "Smith", age= 9}
      , {name="Jane", last ="White", age =5}]

 return [{last="Smith", age =19},
         {last ="White", age =5}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Dict.Extra.groupBy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/dict-extra/2.3.0/Dict-Extra#groupBy) to perform the initial grouping, then sum the ages by mapping over the list and summing the ages:

```elm
import Dict.Extra exposing (groupBy)

familySumAges : List Person -> List Family
familySumAges =
    groupBy .last
        >> Dict.map (\_ -> List.map .age >> List.sum)
        >> Dict.toList
        >> List.map (uncurry Family)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following answer courtesy of @holy-meekrob and @ilias from the Elm Slack channel. https://ellie-app.com/7tqY9w6gNa1/1

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Dict exposing (..)
import Html exposing (text)


type alias Person =
    { name : String
    , last : String
    , age : Int
    }


type alias Family =
    { last : String
    , age : Int
    }


people : List Person
people =
    [ { name = "John"
      , last = "Smith"
      , age = 10
      }
    , { name = "Jason"
      , last = "Smith"
      , age = 9
      }
    , { name = "Jane"
      , last = "White"
      , age = 5
      }
    ]


sumAges : Person -> Dict String Family -> Dict String Family
sumAges person families =

        Dict.update
            person.last
            (\family ->
                case family of
                    Nothing ->
                        Just { last = person.last, age = person.age }

                    Just fam ->
                        Just { last = person.last, age = fam.age + person.age }
            )
            families


main =
    text (toString (List.foldl sumAges Dict.empty people |> Dict.values))
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach is different than the solution you accepted.

If the list of records is sorted, then we could simply aggregate the age as long as the last name remains unchanged.
Otherwise, we'll need to create a new record for the unseen last name.

```
import List
SumAgeByLast data = let
    sorted = List.sortBy .last data
    fst x = List.head x |> Maybe.withDefault {name= "_", last= "_", age= 0}
    agg lst p =if (fst lst).last==p.last then {name = "_", last = p.last ,age = (fst lst).age+p.age} else p::lst
  in
    List.foldl  agg [] sorted
```

We basically iterate over all people `p` and add them to the first element of the list `lst` unless we encounter that last name for the first time, then we prepend it `p::lst`

Test it with

```
data = [{name= "John", last= "Smith", age= 10},{name="Jason", last= "Smith", age= 9}, {name="Jane", last ="White", age =5}]
SumByLast data
```

Obviously, this function could be made generic, if we pass `.last` and `.age` as parameters